# How to set the thread count in parallel execution of cucumber testng framework?

Tags: java, selenium, maven, cucumber, testng

I would like to limit the parallel execution thread count in cucumber testng framework. Now by default 10 threads (browsers) are getting started.

I am using cucumber-java and cucumber-testng version 7.8.0 and maven-surefire plugin version 3.0.0-M6. And testng version is 7.5

I tried setting thread configurations under maven-surefire-plugin but the same didn't work. Please help me to set the threadcount somewhere so that I can limit the no. of parallel executions in cucumber framework.

I have added the below code in my testrunner file to support parallel execution.

````
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
 
import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
 
@CucumberOptions(tags = "", features = "src/test/resources/features", glue = ""src/test/resources/teststepDefinitions")
 
public class CucumberRunnerTests extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
 
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
 
}```
````

Comment: What's wrong with the surefire plugin? It should work with parallel execution. Could you please share your maven Surefire configuration?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `dataproviderthreadcount`. You can do this through surefire.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-testng#maven-surefire-plugin-configuration-for-parallel-execution

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
         <properties>
            <property>
               <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
               <value>${threadcount}</value>
            </property>
         </properties>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
</plugins>
```